# Parse Error: A server with the specified hostname could not be found.

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I'm currently testing out an iOS app making that makes use of Parse.com's authentication system. Whenever I try to logon to the app using the simulator, I have no issues accessing the database. However, whenever I logon to the app using my iPhone 6, multiple attempts are made at connecting, and in the end I receive the following errors:

```
[Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 2 after sleeping for 3.492912 seconds.
[Error]: A server with the specified hostname could not be found. 
(Code: 100, Version: 1.8.1)
```

The only question I found similar to this says to "keep trying" and eventually it will work, but this has been happening for the past week now. Any ideas?

Comment: reset the simulator, remove the app from your phone... Then make sure that into the parse id is correct the app delegate and make sure that your computer is connected to the net lol :)

Comment: Just tried all of those, still getting the same error :/

Comment: Update to the latest version - 1.8.5 and see if the issue persists

Comment: I've updated, yet the problem is still there.

Comment: Update FB app id on the server. Sound strange? Just try it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently restarting your iPhone will make the error go away, not sure why though. If anyone wants to expand on this feel free, thanks all!